# The defined variable calculation formula is abnormal and cannot be output normally

Tags: python

I wrote a small python digital encryption program
His steps are:

1. enter a four-digit number
2. (Each digit+7)*0.1, replace every digit
3. Exchange the number of the first digit with the number of the third digit
4. Exchange the second digit number with the fourth digit number
5. Output the encrypted four-digit number

My code:

```
nus=int(input("Input a group of four digits as:"))
qa=(int(nus[0])+7)*0.1
se=(int(nus[2])+7)*0.1
er=(int(nus[1])+7)*0.1
uc=(int(nus[3])+7)*0.1
w1=qa=se=er=uc
print("The output encrypted number is:",str(w1))
```

But I can't execute it smoothly, an error occurs after execution

```
Normal execution result:
input
Enter a set of four digits as: 1234
Output
The output encrypted number is: 0189

Error message
qa=(int(nus[0])+7)*0.1
TypeError:'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `nus=input("Input a group of four digits as:")` remove int conversion, you can't access i[0] if i is an int

Comment: But the answer output is wrong
The correct answer should be 0189
Can I ask you for assistance?

Comment: After doing the operations, the values are `[1.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.9]` then you need only the 0 1 8 9 part ? Your requirement is missing something because you end up with float and you want one digit

Comment: The final correct output is 0189
Is a four-digit integer
Not a float

Comment: I get it,**BUT** with the steps you give, the 4 values at the end are `1.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.9`, because the `*0.1` operation make ints becomes floats, like 8 becomes 0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `nus` is an `int` you can"t take the `i-th` element of, keep it a string. And `w1=qa=se=er=uc` is surely not what you want, that gives the value of `uc` to the 4 other variables.

---

With the steps you mentionned

```
nb = input("Give a 4-digit value: ")
values = [(int(i) + 7) * 0.1 for i in nb]   # do (x+7) * 0.1
values[0], values[2] = values[2], values[0] # switch first and third
values[1], values[3] = values[3], values[1] # switch second and fourth
```

But for `'1234'` that ends up with `[1.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.9]`

---

To get `0189` I'd say the operation would `(x+7) % 10` to keep the last digit only

```
nb = '1234'
values = [str((int(i) + 7) % 10) for i in nb]
values = values[2], values[3], values[0], values[1] # one-liner switch
result = "".join(values)
print(result)  # 0189
```